# Problem at trigger firing

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement on Trigger and scenario is given below

I created a field called **amount** on Account and contact objects. Later i created a record for account called AAA where amount value is nothing. Under this account record AAA, i created two contacts records named CCC1 and CCC2 with amount value is some x1 and x2 respectively.

After creating this contacts under this account record, i need to update the record AAA amount value with sum of x1 and x2. Like this, if i create one more contact record CCC3(Let say) under AAA, then amount value of account record should be updated with sum of x1+x2+x3. Likewise if i delete one contact record from AAA, then amount for AAA is should be sum of remaining contacts and vice versa for if i update contacts amount values.

To do this, I developed the following trigger.

```
Trigger Amount_Total_on_Contact on Contact (after insert) {

    List<Account> acc1 = new List<Account>();
List<Account> acc = [select Amount__c,(select AccountId from contacts where AccountId in:Trigger.OldMap.keySet())from account];
AggregateResult results=[select sum(Amount__c)total from Contact where AccountId in:Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
    for(Contact cc: Trigger.New) {
        for(Account a: acc) {
            a.Amount__c = (Decimal)results.get('total');
            acc1.add(a);
        }
    }
    update acc1;
}
```

**But my problem in this trigger is, amount value of account record is not reflecting.**

Note: Its is not mandatory for using after insert event. I just took it for checking. we can add other events like update and delete.

Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: for this type of lookup rollup, you can use https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in both the SOQL in where clause you are matching `AccountId` with contact ids(`Trigger.oldMap.keySet` is contact ids, since the trigger is on Contact object).

You should do the following.

First get all accountIds from the contacts.

```
for(Contact c : Trigger.New)
{
accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
}
```

Next, query on Contact Object and fetch result by grouping with Account Ids.

```
for(AggregateResult agr : [select AccountId, Sum(NumberField__c) TotalSum from Contact where accountId IN :accountIds group by AccountId])
{
accountListToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=agr.get('AccountId'), NumberField__c=agr.get('TotalSum')));
}
```

You might have to typecast the AggregateResult fields based on your field type.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use dlrs https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries

If not then try with below code.

first collect all the Account ids and then query on contact

```
Trigger Amount_Total_on_Contact on Contact (after insert) {

    List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
    set<Id> setAccountIds = new set<Id>();

    //first iterate over the trigger.new and collect all the account Ids 
    for(contact objContact: Trigger.New)
    {
        if(objContact.AccountId != null)
        {
            setAccountIds.add(objContact.AccountId);
        }
    }
    //now query on contact and get the sum of Amount field and assign to Account list
    for(AggregateResult agResult: [SELECT sum(Amount__c)total, AccountId 
                                     FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN:setAccountIds 
                                     GROUP BY AccountId])
    {
        lstAccount.add(new Account(Id = (Id) agResult.get('AccountId'), 
                                    Amount__c = (Decimal) agResult.get('total')));
    }
    //update your list
    update lstAccount;
}
```

Comment: Its hard to make two acceptable answers
Thank You ratan

Comment: @KSKumaar no problem